# Mono WCF client cannot talk to .NET WCF server when Transport security is enabled

Tags: wcf, mono, net.tcp

Here is how I run WCF host:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:2222/blah");

var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceImpl), baseAddress);
sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, baseAddress);
sh.Open();
```

Here's my client:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:2222/blah");
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
client.Open();
```

When I execute both client and server using Mono 2.10 runtime, all works. But when server is running on .NET 4.0, I get a `System.IO.IOException: Read failure ---> System.Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. I also verified that with `binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None` all works fine. Is there a possibility that I could somehow make those two runtimes interoperate with properly working security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, support for `NetTcpBinding` is very limited in Mono and it does not support any kind of security.

If you only look at the source of of [NetTcpBinding.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/NetTcpBinding.cs#L232), it may appear that it does, but if you look at the actual binding elements, you'll see a lot of methods that are not implemented.

I actually ran into the same problem a couple of days ago while I was working on my new WCF configuration system, wanted to get `NetTcpBinding` working with security and when I investigated why it was not working, I realised that too much is not implemented, so it's probably a larger task to get it working.

Also note that by default, `NetTcpBinding` uses `WindowsStreamSecurityBindingElement` - unfortunately, I could not find any documentation on the underlying transport mechanism.

Use `BasicHttpBinding` or the new `BasicHttpsBinding` if you're using .NET 4.5 (it will also be available in MonoTouch shortly).

Comment: Is this still current?